# Print Decoded Data after SSLEngine Handshake is FINISHED

Tags: java, ssl, nio, nio2, sslengine

How do I get the decoded data after the SSL Handshake is complete?

At the moment it seems to decrypt just some of the data.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Save and Run [this code](https://github.com/ThreaT/WebServers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/webservers/HttpsServer.java)
2. Go to https://localhost:1500 - You should notice the beginning and end of the request has something like:

> ?GET ... #$?+{???u7Y???

Comment: While a link to the full code can be useful, could you also include (a) the relevant section of code with enough context to understand it (e.g., what is the type of sc), and (b) a description of what "get stuck" means, including a stack trace if you have one.

Comment: Your code does not even work as described (JDK8):
Https Server started in 114ms.
java.nio.channels.WritePendingException
 at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:352)
 at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:387)
 at Test.doHandshake(Test.java:112)
 at Test.access$12(Test.java:106)
 at Test$1.completed(Test.java:75)
 at Test$1.completed(Test.java:1)
 at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)

Comment: @SkateScout: Works for me. I'm using this run command: `/home/myuser/Desktop/Stuff/Test/WebServers; JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_40 /usr/local/netbeans-8.0.2/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.webservers.HttpsServer" -Dexec.executable=/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec`

Comment: I think you should read the SSLEngine Dokumentation carefully.

Line 54 - 62 : Should be done outside the loop
Line 114 : write to Socket even if there is some outstanding write
           -> This can throw an exception
Line 197 : allocate always new buffer
Line 182 : write "Response" before read the request
Line 202 : Wait up over one hour
Line 206 : Print output even if there was no bytes produced by the engine
Line 209 : Ignores Buffer Overflow

Comment: @SkateScout: I've applied most of your above recommendations. I'll be honest, I don't get some of the others though. Would you care enough to add a pull request or answer by any chance?

Comment: Looks like very bad thing in your code: `request = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(inputBuffer).toString();`. Here should be explicitly specified needed charset. This could lead to your problem.

Comment: Also the problem can not be reproduced